# Calculate ratios of counts of rows with subqueries

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

(I could not think of a better title for this question.  Suggestions welcome.)

(In case versions matter, I'm using SQLAlchemy 1.4.4 and Postgresql 13.1.)

I have a table ('test') of multiple instances of boolean values for multiple persons, representing test results (pass or fail), and I want to create a query returning a result set representing pass/fail ratios for each of them.

I.e., for this table:

```
 id | person | passed
----+--------+--------
  1 | p1     | t
  2 | p1     | f
  3 | p1     | f
  4 | p2     | t
  5 | p2     | t
  6 | p2     | t
  7 | p2     | t
  8 | p2     | t
  9 | p2     | f
 10 | p2     | f
 11 | p2     | f
```

the query should return:

```
person | pass_fail_ratio
-------+-------------------
p1     | 0.5
p2     | 1.6666666666666667
```

Here is the solution I have been able to come up with so far.  (I'm appending a complete MWE to the end.)

```
results_count = (
    sa.select(
        test.person,
        test.passed,
        sa.func.count(test.passed).label('count')
    ).group_by(test.person).group_by(test.passed)
).subquery()

pass_count = (
    sa.select(results_count.c.person, results_count.c.count)
    .filter(results_count.c.passed == True)  # noqa
).subquery()

fail_count = (
    sa.select(results_count.c.person, results_count.c.count)
    .filter(results_count.c.passed == False)  # noqa
).subquery()

pass_fail_ratio = (
    sa.select(
        pass_count.c.person,
        (
            sa.cast(pass_count.c.count, sa.Float)
            / sa.cast(fail_count.c.count, sa.Float)
        ).label('success_failure_ratio')
    )
).filter(fail_count.c.person == pass_count.c.person)
```

To me, this looks overly complicated for what would seem to be a conceptually rather simple thing.  Is there a better solution?

---

MWE:

```
# To change database name, modify 'dbname'.

# Expected output:
# ('p1', 0.5)
# ('p2', 1.6666666666666667)

# Lots of constraints and checks omitted for brevity.

# To view generated SQL, uncomment the line containing "echo" below.

import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as orm
import sqlalchemy.types as types

dbname = 'test'


base = orm.declarative_base()


class test(base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    person = sa.Column(sa.String)
    passed = sa.Column(types.Boolean)
    pass


engine = sa.create_engine(
    f"postgresql://localhost:5432/{dbname}", future=True
)
base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = orm.Session(engine)

# Add some data.
session.add(test(person='p1', passed=True))
session.add(test(person='p1', passed=False))
session.add(test(person='p1', passed=False))
session.add(test(person='p2', passed=True))
session.add(test(person='p2', passed=True))
session.add(test(person='p2', passed=True))
session.add(test(person='p2', passed=True))
session.add(test(person='p2', passed=True))
session.add(test(person='p2', passed=False))
session.add(test(person='p2', passed=False))
session.add(test(person='p2', passed=False))
session.commit()

results_count = (
    sa.select(
        test.person,
        test.passed,
        sa.func.count(test.passed).label('count')
    ).group_by(test.person).group_by(test.passed)
).subquery()

pass_count = (
    sa.select(results_count.c.person, results_count.c.count)
    .filter(results_count.c.passed == True)  # noqa
).subquery()

fail_count = (
    sa.select(results_count.c.person, results_count.c.count)
    .filter(results_count.c.passed == False)  # noqa
).subquery()

pass_fail_ratio = (
    sa.select(
        pass_count.c.person,
        (
            sa.cast(pass_count.c.count, sa.Float)
            / sa.cast(fail_count.c.count, sa.Float)
        ).label('success_failure_ratio')
    )
).filter(fail_count.c.person == pass_count.c.person)

# engine.echo = True
with orm.Session(engine) as session:
    res = session.execute(pass_fail_ratio)
    for row in res:
        print(row)
        pass
    pass
pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is soooo complicated.  I wouldn't use subqueries.  One method is:

```
select person,
       count(*) filter (where passed) * 1.0 / count(*) filter (where not passed)
from test t
group by person;
```

You might find it more convenient to express this "in the old-fashioned way" without `filter`:

```
select person,
       sum( passed::int ) * 1.0 / sum( (not passed)::int )
from test t
group by person;
```

Note that the *pass ratio* is more commonly used than the ratio of passes to fails.  That is simply:

```
select person,
       avg( passed::int ) as pass_ratio
from test t
group by person;
```

Comment: Wow, that was a killer!  As someone whose knowledge of SQL is, to put it mildly, not perfect, I did not know about FILTER.

Comment: As for the pass/fail vs. pass/all ratio part, I have my reasons :-)

Comment: @toomas . . . `FILTER` is standard SQL, but Postgres is one of the few databases that implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Got Gordon Linoff's answer working in SQLAlchemy.  Here is my final solution:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
pass_fail_ratio_query = sa.select(
        test.person,
        (
            sa.cast(
                sa.funcfilter(sa.func.count(), test.passed == True),  # noqa
                sa.Float
            )
            / sa.cast(
                sa.funcfilter(sa.func.count(), test.passed == False),  # noqa
                sa.Float
            )
        )
    ).group_by(test.person)
```